# Validation of fetched data from API Redux React

Tags: api, validation, reactjs, redux, store

So, I will go straight to the point. I am getting such data from api:

```
[
{
    id: 123,
    email: asd@asd.com
},
{
    id: 456,
    email: asdasd.com
},
{
    id: 789,
    email: asd@asd
},
...
```

]

and I should validate email and show this all info in a list, something like this:

1. asd@asd.com - valid
2. asdasd.com - invalid
3. asd@asd - invalid 
   ...

My question is what is the best way to store validation data in a store? Is it better to have something like "isValid" property by each email? I mean like this:

```
store = {
emailsById: [
    123: {
        value: asd@asd.com,
        isValid: true
    },
    456: {
        value: asdasd.com,
        isValid: false
    },
    789: {
        value: asd@asd,
        isValid: false
    }
    ...
]
```

}

or something like this:

```
store = {
emailsById: [
    123: {
        value: asd@asd.com
    },
    456: {
        value: asdasd.com
    },
    789: {
        value: asd@asd
    }
    ...
],
inValidIds: ['456', '789']
```

}

which one is better? Or maybe there is some another better way to have such data in store? Have in mind that there can be thousands emails in a list :)

Thanks in advance for the answers ;)

Comment: I guess it really depends on what you are doing with that data.

I would probably just keep everything together so you can filter and sort as needed. For example, if you have them in separate arrays then you will have to concat them sort the list by email address or some other field.

Comment: yes, I do understand that I can store my data both ways. but my question is which way is the right way? how people usually store data in redux stores? I am new to all redux stuff, so I am just trying to do things "the right way" from the beggining. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend reading the article "*Avoiding Accidental Complexity When Structuring Your App State*" by Tal Kol which answers exactly your problem: https://hackernoon.com/avoiding-accidental-complexity-when-structuring-your-app-state-6e6d22ad5e2a

Your example is quite simplistic and everything really depends on your needs but personally I would go with something like this (based on linked article):

```
var store = {
  emailsById: {
    123: {
      value: '123@example.com',
    },
    456: {
      value: '456@example.com',
    },
    789: {
      value: '789@example.com',
    },
    // ...
  },
  validEmailsMap: {
    456: true, // true when valid
    789: false, // false when invalid
  },
};
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, the way you defined an array in javascript is wrong. 
What you need is an array of objects like,

```js
emails : [
  {
    id: '1',
    email: 'abc@abc.com',
    isValid: true
  },
  {
    id: '2',
    email: 'abc.com',
    isValid: false;
  }
];
```

if you need do access email based on an id, you can add an id property along with email and isValid. [uuid](https://www.npmjs.com/package/uuid) is a good way to go about it.

In conclusion, it depends upon your use case.

I believe, the above example is a good way to keep data in store because it's simple.

What you described in your second example is like maintaining two different states. I would not recommend that.

Comment: well thanks for the answer. :) and regarding correctness of the array, it's actually not the point, "id" is also not the point here. my question is which way is the correct way of storing data in a store? my example is just an simple example, there is more data. in the end there should be something like a table with each cell validated.it will be something like this:

id | email | date | user | url

and each of these values should be validated before showing them in a list. and I do understand that I can store my data both ways,but which one is "the right" way of having data in a store? :)

Comment: You're actually wrong, that is a perfectly valid and common use for initializing arrays

Answer (score 0):

So your best option would be to create a separate file that will contain all your validations methods. Import that into the component you're using and then when you want to use the logic for valid/invalid.

If its something that you feel you want to put in the store from the beginning and the data will never be in a transient state you could parse your DTO through an array map in your reducer when you get the response from your API.

```
export default function (state = initialState, action) {
    const {type, response} = action

    switch (type) {
        case DATA_RECIEVED_SUCCESS:
            const items = []

            for (var i = 0; i < response.emailsById.length; i++) {
                var email = response.emailsById[i];

                email.isValid = checkEmailValid(email)

                items.push(email)
            }

            return {
                ...state,
                items
            }
    }
}
```

However my preference would be to always check at the last moment you need to. It makes it a safer design in case you find you need to change you design in the future. Also separating the validation logic out will make it more testable